# I am trying to combine a button's coding and servo's coding. But it is still cannot be verified. What have I done wrong?

Tags: servo, button

## include

Servo myservo;

void setup(){
  myservo.attach(8);
   pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  myservo.write(0);
  delay(3);
  myservo.write(90);
  delay(3);
}
 const int inPin=8;
 const int outPin = 9;
 int currentState = LOW;
  currentState = digitalRead (inPin);
  if (currentState== HIGH)
    digitalWrite (outPin,HIGH);
   else
    digitalWrite (outPin,HIGH);
   delay(10);
 }

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use two loop() and setup() function.

You can refer to a similar combination between Servo Motor code and Potentiometer code [here](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-servo-motor-controlled-by-potentiometer).

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful website